# Table in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I want to build a table in Angular 2.

This table should look like this

[image]

I have a `Component`, which fives me a data

```
export class ResultsComponent implements OnInit {
  public items: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.items = ['app1', 'item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'app2', 'item4',
            'item5', 'item6', 'app3', 'item7', 'item8', 'item9'];
    this.buildArr(this.items);
  }

  buildArr(theArr: any[]) {
    const arrOfarr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < theArr.length ; i += 4) {
      const row = [];
      for (let j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        const value = theArr[i + j];
        if (!value) {
          break;
        }
        row.push(value);
      }
      arrOfarr.push(row);
    }
    return arrOfarr;
  }
```

And here is my `Template`

```
<h1>Results</h1>
<table class="table" id="myTable" class="table">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Part 1</th>
    <th>Part 2</th>
    <th>Part 3</th>
    <th>Part 4</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

  <tr *ngFor="let row of buildArr(items);let i = index">
    <td *ngFor="let item of row">{{item}}</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

But here is what I get

[image: The result]

How could i achieve the table, that I need?
And how could I insert in the table cell, that contains message "Doesn't exist!"?

Comment: Not clear how `['app1', 'item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'app2', 'item4',
            'item5', 'item6', 'app3', 'item7', 'item8', 'item9']` maps to table. You could at least use part and page items in array same as in images.

Comment: @dfsq Sorry, my fault - I edited the question by adding new screenshot

Comment: What is the rule where you detect that the item doesn't exist so you can insert it? You data structure doesn't to support any logic for that

Comment: it is just a message from json, so I tried to push in on the certain plave, but it doesnt work, so I guess I need to make an extra column for this

Answer (score 0):

**You just need to fill in the rest of each row with your "does not exist" text.** There is surely a more optimized way to do this if you can turn your items array into a list of objects or a map.

Shown below is a small change to existing code to fill in the indices with "does not exist" text

```js
export class ResultsComponent implements OnInit {
  public items: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.items = ['app1', 'item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'app2', 'item4',
      'item5', 'item6', 'app3', 'item7', 'item8', 'item9'
    ];

    this.buildArr(this.items);
  }

  buildArr(theArr: any[]) {
    const arrOfarr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < theArr.length; i += 4) {
      const row = [];
      for (let j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        const value = theArr[i + j];
        if (j > 0 && value.substring(0, 2) == "app") { //make sure to skip first item
          while (j < 4) { //finish off row with placeholder string
            row[j] = "does not exist"
          }
          break;
        }
        row.push(value);
      }
      arrOfarr.push(row);
    }
    return arrOfarr;
  }
```

```html
<h1>Results</h1>
<table class="table" id="myTable" class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Part 1</th>
      <th>Part 2</th>
      <th>Part 3</th>
      <th>Part 4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr *ngFor="let row of buildArr(items);let i = index">
      <td *ngFor="let item of row">{{item}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```